# Entity Framework change Id type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I've changed type of Id property from Int to Guid, no other entities reference that Id and I've manually deleted all records of that entity from database, my generated migration class looks like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.RoutineExercises", "RoutineExerciseId", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
}

public override void Down()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.RoutineExercises", "RoutineExerciseId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
}
```

And I'm getting this error when I run update-database command:

> The object 'PK_dbo.RoutineExercises' is dependent on column 'RoutineExerciseId'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN RoutineExerciseId failed because one or more objects access this column.

And my FluentAPI configuration looks like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<RoutineExercise>().HasKey(r => r.RoutineExerciseId);
 modelBuilder.Entity<RoutineExercise>()
                .HasRequired(r => r.Exercise)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.ExerciseId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<RoutineExercise>()
                .HasRequired(r => r.Routine)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.RoutineId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

How can I fix this without dropping whole database ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing the migration in stages - I don't know for sure but your fluent configuration is resulting in the creation of the primary key based on the field you want to change and the migration wizard can't factor in the need to drop the primary key convert the field to a guid and then rebuild a new primary key.

So my suggestion would be to do the migration in baby steps:
1. Remove the haskey from routineexerciseid and move it to another field or make a new composite key- ef needs a primary key
2. With the primary key moved you should be able to alter the column
3. Finally reinstate the primary key on that column.

Alternatively
Create a completely new column as a guid as the primary key, drop the old column and then if necessary rename the new column as required

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else is looking for this answer, I just found it out myself.  You need to drop the primary key before alters.

DropPrimaryKey("dbo.RoutineExercises",new[] { "RoutineExerciseId"});

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do a Migration Reset than changing a lot of things and possibly messing up your database. I do recommend making a back up of your data before proceeding with this though.

The process is outlined here:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate